# Proving a language is regular or not?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I'm trying to understand how to prove a language is regular or not regular, for example this language: $$L=\{a^nb^m:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\land n+m=5 \}$$
Is this language regular or not?

**My solution**
Using the pumping lemma, I can choose a string with a pumping length $p$ like: $w=a^{5-p}b^p$, then $x = a^j, y=a^l$ and $z=a^kb^p$ such that $j+l+k=5-p$, I will pump with $i=0$, so the string will be $xz=a^{j+k}b^p$, this is not regular because $j+k<p$.

Am I right about this ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: This language is finite, so it is regular.

Comment: How do you know that the language is finite ?

Comment: @David $L=\{a^5,a^4b,a^3b^2,a^2,b^3,ab^4,b^5\}$.

Comment: If this language is regular, then why when I use pumping lemma, the result is not regular ?

Comment: Maybe you're not using the pumping lemma the right way? Don't get fixated on that lemma. To a man with a hammer...

Comment: What I believe your argument shows is that no words of $\ L\ $ *of length*  $5$ *or less* can be pumped, so its pumping length must be at least $6$.  But since $\ L\ $ contains *no* words of length $6$ or more, it is vacuously true that *all* of them can be pumped.  That is, $\ L\ $ has a pumping length of $6$.